# Update the new and old about pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, help-center

Another occurence of the `Faq` word that should be removed. (There should be a tag about this)

The new about page on pretty much every site displays a nice button :

[image]

I want to visit that section. Where is it ? That should be changed to :

[image]

The old about page (on meta) as two occurences :

[image]
[image]

Comment: The second occurences could be solved by giving meta it's new about page ^.^

Answer (score 2):

These have been fixed now.

[image: meta]

[image: main]